# C# AWS Lambda functions with React

Tags: c#, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

**Background**: I followed the tutorial on serverless-stack.com and my website is working nicely. I now want to replace the backend (Nodejs) with C#.

I tried a couple of things.

First I tried ASP.NET, but it seems very complicated (never done ASP before) and when I published to lambda I was getting Cors issues on the React side. I was able to fix the cors issue, but now I am getting 404 not found. I have a feeling that ASP.NET is a little much for what I am trying to do anyways (just querying a database and passing the results to the frontend).

I then tried to create lambda functions in C#, but the example doesn't create a JSON response similar to the Nodejs lambda functions, how will my react frontend interact with that? (I am using aws-amplify)

I have also heard of WCF but I also don't have any experience with that either.

**Crux of the matter**

So my question is, for light weight functions and minimal-clean code which route would be the easiest / best (ASP.NET, Lambda C#, or WCF) and how would I get them to correctly talk to my react frontend?

Thanks I have been spending the last 2 weekends working on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in C# and Lambda. You'll have to serialize your final result into JSON format using a library such as Newtonsoft.JSON:

```
string resp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<SomeType>(obj);
return resp;
```

Comment: Okay I tried your method, and it comes back as a string on the react side, I want it to come back as JSON (similarly to how I use it with NodeJS)

Comment: For that you'll need to set the content-type header value to application/json. If you use AWS API-Gateway, this will be available as Headers property of the APIGatewayProxyResponse.

Otherwise, you can also deserialize the JSON string on the React side.